# Map and the contents from the contents pane disappeared in ArcGIS Pro. How to fix it?

Tags: arcgis-pro

[image]

While I was trying to zoom in and out using ctrl + Mouse scroll, all the data in map view and contents pan disappeared. I restarted ArcGIS Pro and tried to reload the data, but every time it showed the same blank window (as given below). How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Where did it disappear? Did you try a new project with a map?

Comment: What happens if you go to view > catalog pane? Can you see the map under the Maps section, then open it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this prompt and then you will be able to see your map again.

View -> Catalog Pane -> Maps (expand the Maps and double click on Map). Here is a screenshot.

[image]